# Javascript / CSS issue on displaying site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm playing around with building a template I've purchased onto our CMS to see how it displays, and am largely there, but I cannot get the text to correctly display.

This is the [template](http://www.pixelglow.ro/themes/planus/1/index.html) I am using.

Our CMS is custom, and is running here.  While based on bootstrap2 in the code, I'm also looking to get it updated to bootstrap3 as part of this.

It is running here: [style demo site](http://tinyurl.com/o8v8a29)

Problem at the moment is none of the text is showing, and I can't figure out what is preventing this?

Comment: In Firefox I see error: TypeError: this.el is null
 
...ections = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.cbp-so-section...

Comment: Yes, I've not added the body tag in to affix the scrollto, but didn't think that would affect the main display.

Comment: what have you done to debug the site?

Comment: The version of jquery 1.10.x in the template vs jquery 1.9.x in the demo?

Comment: No, have just tried with the latest version of jquery, no difference.

Comment: The opacity of all content is for example .jumbotron h1 {opacity: 0;}
In the demo it should add to the section the class cbp-so-animate to update that style but it does not.

Comment: See my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script needs an id on the body. I tested it on a local copy. That does the trick!.

```
<body id="cbp-so-scroller">
```

Otherwise this.el is null in  cbpScroller.js

```
// Slide effect on sections
new cbpScroller( document.getElementById( 'cbp-so-scroller' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelectorAll' of null
```

Basically means you've not got the required element in the DOM for this function to fire. I think it's having a trickle-down effect with your content (your content loads via JS?)

I had a look at your code and it looks like this is the offending line:

```
this.sections = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.cbp-so-section' ) );
```

Do you have the `.cbp-so-section` element available? If you either remove this line, or put the right element into the DOM, you should fix the issue

Comment: It is in his demo - <section id="about" class="cbp-so-section cbp-so-init">
Problem is that TypeError: this.el is null

Comment: :) good point! Hope my answer does shine some light on the issue

Comment: Thanks Rich, I hadn't added that in as it needed a full code change to apply, but surprised that the default on this was to display no text.  Thank you for your help.